# Hibernate UUID as UUID type

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, spring-data, h2

Trying to use a `UUID` as my id for PostgreSQL and H2, the current exceptions are for H2

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.UUID field com.lm.model.Task.id to java.lang.String
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:758)
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectSetter.set(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:122)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:381)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4751)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:184)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.persist(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:289)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.persist(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:389)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:405)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:390)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.save(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.rest.core.invoke.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:106)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.createAndReturn(RepositoryEntityController.java:383)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:211)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Task.class);

@Id
@NotNull
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "task_id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
private UUID id;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 1, max = 120)
private String description;


public String getDescription () {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription (final String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public UUID getId () {
    return id;
}

public void setId ( final UUID uuid ) {
    id = uuid;
}
}
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using a Spring Data Rest Repository to persist this.

I would like to be able to persist, ultimately, as the native type in PostgreSQL, and whatever it is H2 needs the UUID to be (I'm fairly new to H2).

Comment: A simple `@Id  @GeneratedValue
    private java.util.UUID id;`
works in Hibernate 5+ on H. See [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers). Probably also works on other databases.

Comment: @NatanCox funny I never updated this answer after getting them to make the feature

Comment: @NatanCox updated my answer to include the text I wrote for the [pgjdbc bug](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/247)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** with Hibernate 5 [I was able to get more cross database compatible UUID's included](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9562) (note: I am not the implementor, though I did give it a stab).

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column( columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false )
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**Original**

[Dzone posted an article about a second version of the UUID generator last year](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers)

first create your own usertype (at least until hibernate implements similar)

```
public class UUIDType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<UUID> {
public static final String NAME = "uuid-name";
public static final UUIDType INSTANCE = new UUIDType();

public UUIDType() {
    super( UUIDSqlTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, UUIDTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE );
}

public String getName() {
    return NAME;
}

public static class UUIDSqlTypeDescriptor implements SqlTypeDescriptor {
    public static final UUIDSqlTypeDescriptor INSTANCE = new UUIDSqlTypeDescriptor();

    public int getSqlType() {
        // ugh
        return Types.VARCHAR;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canBeRemapped() {
        return true;
    }

    public <X> ValueBinder<X> getBinder( final JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor ) {
        return new BasicBinder<X>( javaTypeDescriptor, this ) {
            @Override
            protected void doBind( PreparedStatement st, X value, int index, WrapperOptions options )
                    throws SQLException {
                st.setObject( index, javaTypeDescriptor.unwrap( value, UUID.class, options ) );
            }
        };
    }

    public <X> ValueExtractor<X> getExtractor( final JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor ) {
        return new BasicExtractor<X>( javaTypeDescriptor, this ) {
            @Override
            protected X doExtract( ResultSet rs, String name, WrapperOptions options ) throws SQLException {
                return javaTypeDescriptor.wrap( rs.getObject( name ), options );
            }

            @Override
            protected X doExtract( CallableStatement statement, int index, WrapperOptions options )
                    throws SQLException {
                return javaTypeDescriptor.wrap( statement.getObject( index ), options );
            }

            @Override
            protected X doExtract( CallableStatement statement, String name, WrapperOptions options )
                    throws SQLException {
                return javaTypeDescriptor.wrap( statement.getObject( name ), options );
            }
        };
    }
}
}
```

Then annotate your models `package-info.java`

```
 @TypeDef(
    name = UUIDType.NAME,
    defaultForType = UUID.class,
    typeClass = UUIDType.class
)
package com.xenoterracide.rpf.model;


import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.type.UUIDType;

import java.util.UUID;
```

finally in your entity

```
@Id
@Override
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}
```