# Unable to delete entity with UUID as ID

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity, uuid

I am developing a Spring boot application where one of the entities have UUID as ID. When I try to delete the entity, I get the below error with 400. Any input is highly appreciated. I am a new learner, so please be gentle :) Thanks.

```
Field error in object 'UUID' on field 'mostSigBits': rejected value [null]; codes [typeMismatch.UUID.mostSigBits,typeMismatch.mostSigBits,typeMismatch.long,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [UUID.mostSigBits,mostSigBits]; arguments []; default message [mostSigBits]]; default message [Failed to convert value of type 'null' to required type 'long'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [null] to type [long] for value 'null'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type]
```

Comment: I think  your JPA provider does not understand `UUID` type so tries to save it as entity with `mostSigBits` etc fields. What database do you use? What is JPA provider?

Comment: For example, here is how you make Hibernate aware of UUID https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611285/hibernate-uuid-as-uuid-type

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of it in the following code snippet.

```
 @Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = “UUID”)
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = “UUID”,
        strategy = “org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator”,
    )
    @Column(name = “id”, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    
    …
}
```

you can read more from [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/)

Comment: I am autogenerating the UUID by using the below annotations

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "u")
@GenericGenerator(name = "u", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
```

Comment: I added the 'Column' annotation but still getting the same issue. I have a 'OneToMany' mapping to another Entity BookCategory which also have UUID as id. But for the book entity I am trying to delete, there is no BookCategory attached. I am not sure why I am getting the error :(

Comment: if you have OneToMany relationship then must you have to delete reference record first

Comment: but the reference record doesn't exist. It's just an empty list as I didn't add any book categories to the book